# Are rhumb lines ever used as leg paths for RNP/RNAV?

Tags: rnav, arinc-424

Are rhumb lines ever used by an FMS as leg paths for RNP/RNAV? If so, what arinc 424 leg type would use them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The FMS does not use rhumb lines.

All RNP/RNAV flight path legs are geodesics. The only exceptions are RF legs (a constant radius circular path about a turn center) and hold legs (a closed racetrack pattern).

To quote RTCA DO-236C, Minimum Aviation System Performance Standards: Required Navigation Performance for Area Navigation:

> RNP Routes and user-preferred trajectories are assumed to use a series
>   of fixes. The desired path is defined by a series of geodesic tracks
>   joining successive fixes.

It also includes the following definition:

> GEODESIC LINE [Bowditch]
>   A line of shortest distance between any two points on a mathematically
>   defined surface. A geodesic line is a line of double curvature and
>   usually lies between the two normal section lines which the two points
>   determine. If the two terminal points are nearly in the same latitude,
>   the geodesic line may cross one of the normal section lines. It should
>   be noted that, except along the equator and along the meridians, the
>   geodesic line is not a plane curve and cannot be sighted over
>   directly.

Comment: thank you very much